# Filter out certain events from CloudTrail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-quicksight, amazon-cloudtrail

My ultimate goal is to build an workflow whereby we can collect Quicksight related events and then visualize them in Quicksight itself (basically to see dashboard/user usage).  This is all helpfully described on the AWS Blog (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-an-administrative-console-in-amazon-quicksight-to-analyze-usage-metrics/)

My question is around how I can create a Trail that only streams Quicksight related events to S3.  If I create a trail and select data events, I'm getting all kinds of events that I don't care about.  Is there a way to create a trail for just the Quicksight service or any alternative route to not clog up S3 with logs I don't need?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably configure the CloudTrail data event source to be Quicksight.

See "Logging data events with basic event selectors in the AWS Management Console" in this guide

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/logging-data-events-with-cloudtrail.html

Answer (score 0):

Either create a trail with custom event selector using cli,try `put-event-selectors` command to specify the event source as QuickSight.

Or you can try Querying AWS CloudTrail logs via athena https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudtrail-logs.html